# $scope.watch in two different views

Tags: angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Footballing angular JS webb app using Firebase as the backend. Below is the JS of one view:

```
 databaseService.users.child(user.uid).once('value', function(usersSnapshot){
    var users = usersSnapshot.val();
    var selection = users.selection;
    var team = users.teamname;
    var week1 = users.week1;
    var week2 = users.week2;
    var week3 = users.week3;
    var week4 = users.week4;
    var week5 = users.week5;
    var week6 = users.week6;
    var week7 = users.week7;
    var week8 = users.week8;
    var week9 = users.week9;
    var week10 = users.week10;
    var week11 = users.week11;
    var week12 = users.week12;

 $scope.$watch('players', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.totalPoints =(newValue, 'goals');
    firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).child("week12");.set($scope.totalPoints);

},true);
```

So basically the player weekly goals are watched and reflected in the view, after which the updated goal tally of a player is `$set` to a firebase node.

Below are the lines of code used to then update the the season goal tally:

```
 var addition = week1 + week2 + week3 + week4 + week5 + week6 + week7 + week8 + week9 + week10 + week11 + week12;
      var seasonTotal = firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).child("total");


    seasonTotal.set(addition);
```

on the Second view, I have the following code to show the value of firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).child("total"); :

```
  databaseService.users.child(user.uid).on('value', function(usersSnapshot){
    var users = usersSnapshot.val();
    var total = users.total;
$scope.total = total;
```

My Issue

My issue is that when i change the goal tally of a player in my firebase databse weekly node directly (As would be done each week), the goal update is reflected in the first view in real time. However, when I am on the second view, and I make the change in my database, the change update does not reflect in real time (the total goal tally for the weeks); the page needs to be refreshed or i need to return to the first view  AND THEN go back to the second view.

I understand that this is because the code that adds up the weekly goals is in the first JS and not the JS for the second view. But is there a way to get the season total to update irrespective of the page the user is on?